# how use rebound api to move chat head bubble smoothly

Tags: android, facebook, chat, head, android-windowmanager

i am developing a browser like same as in https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.linkbubble.playstore this link. i have develop may things like that browser but i want to move bubble like Facebook chat head and want to show close bubble at the bottom of screen but i can do this thing. i have attached bubble with window manager but i can't move that bubble smoothly. i have searched a rebound api to apply spring animation but there is no way how to use that api to move bubble. please help me. i am searching for this for a week but i can not find any solution.i want to make same functionality like the browser in above link of GOOGLE play

Answer (score 2):

This is **chat head application sample**. You can reference that project. Hope for help. https://github.com/leanmazzu/chat-head-demo

Modify : github link is dead therefore [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwBZbYWEO-10d2poRXg1NnU4OVU/view) is my downloaded file.

Update 19.02.2016

[Chat head Sample 1](https://github.com/henrychuangtw/Android-ChatHead)

[Chat head Sample 2](https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/springy-heads)

[Chat head Sample 3](https://github.com/txusballesteros/bubbles-for-android)

Comment: i have download this demo but this not as i want it worked same as i have implemented but i want to move bubble smoothly like Facebook chat head if i drag chat head to bottom automatically a close bubble come and catch that view and remove all views.it seems natural movement.

Comment: I said, you can reference that application. This application function is basic. Just for reference.

Comment: That sample application is my mention for you. I also reference with that sample application. This is my application in play store. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=bm.mm.magicdictionary

Comment: nice app. but i need some another thing like in https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.linkbubble.playstore this same to same.

Comment: @BM thanks a lot for your reference link,  I resolve my issues very easly to remove the chat heads bubble form the window which stuck for me.

Comment: reference link is not found!!

Comment: my downloaded file. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwBZbYWEO-10d2poRXg1NnU4OVU/view